# popToRootViewController without animation crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have a strange problem here. I have a navigation controller set for 2nd tab and if user taps on 1st tab and taps on 2nd tab, then when user taps I am poping to root view controller with out animation. The strange problem I am facing here is if I set animation bool value to YES then the app will not crash else it will crash. The crash says I am calling "respondsToSelector:" method is called in one of the controller from the stack which successfully gets deallocated when I make a pop call. I am not understanding if animation to NO for the above it crashes. Can some one shed light on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can some one provide me solution for my problem? I am waiting.

Comment: Can you provide more information? A sample of your sourcecode, where you pop to the rootviewcontroller for Example. I'm having a similar problem, where i want to pop to the rootviewcontroller, when i tap on a certain tab, but i just get a bad Access error, when i'm not already in the rootViewController.

Comment: you need to be a bit more clear in what you are asking for. I can only guess, your viewWillAppear (or viewWillDisappear) has a line [super viewWillAppearAnimated:YES]; instead of [super viewWillAppearAnimated:animated];  More info, more code will be useful

Comment: Thank you all, this issue has been fixed. There was issue happening wrt core data and usage of blocks. We figured out and fixed the same. Once again thanks for your inputs.